# Server(C) on the PI doesn't make connection with Client(Java)

Tags: java, android, git, sockets

I have 1 client written in Java and 1 server on the PI written in C making connection through a socket.

At first the server and the client could talk to each other. After a git merge it didn't work anymore but nothing has changed. Can someone see what's wrong?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Udpclient:

```
package com.example.jobush50.test2;

import android.os.Message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Udpclient extends Thread {


    String ipaddress;
    int port;

    DatagramSocket socket;
    InetAddress address;

    String msg;

    public Udpclient(String addr, int prt) {
        ipaddress = addr;
        port = prt;
    }

    public void message(String message) {
        msg = message;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            address = InetAddress.getByName(ipaddress);

            // send request
            byte[] buf;
            buf = msg.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket packet =
                    new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity - Where socket is made:

```
package com.example.jobush50.test2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
    Button buttonConnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ip);
        editTextPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_port);
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Connect_button);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                String ip = editTextAddress.getText().toString();
                int port =  Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString());

                //udpclient = new Udpclient(ip,port);
                //udpclient.start();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("ip", ip);
                intent.putExtra("port", port);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message variable is empty, causing a NULL pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but you have commented out the part where you create a new udpclient and start it.

Comment: It's solved! Well that wasn't the problem I thought it was that too. The output that I received was about an NULLpointer execption in the message. It was empty... and that was making the error. Thanks for you're message!